# cakephp elements MissingViewException

Tags: cakephp, element, cakephp-2.0

When I upload my cakePHP 2.0.0 app to my host I get a MissingViewException when I am calling an function via ajax. This returns an json object made by an element. On my local xampp everything is working fine, but when I upload it to my host, bytebob.com, I get the exception.

I have tried to make changes to my .htaccess like described [in the advanced CakePHP installation page](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/installation/advanced-installation.html), but it doesn't change anything.

Here is the error log:

```
2011-10-25 18:26:04 Error: [MissingViewException] View file "/jalmar/app/View/elements/json.ctp" is missing.
0 /home/sites/jayar.dk/public_html/jalmar/lib/Cake/View/View.php(363): View->_getViewFileName('/elements/json')
1 /home/sites/jayar.dk/public_html/jalmar/lib/Cake/Controller/Controller.php(898): View->render('/elements/json', NULL)
2 /home/sites/jayar.dk/public_html/jalmar/app/Controller/AppController.php(22): Controller->render('/elements/json')
3 /home/sites/jayar.dk/public_html/jalmar/app/Controller/TilmeldingsController.php(147): AppController->sendJson(Array, Array)
4 [internal function]: TilmeldingsController->check_glogon()
```

The host is running php as a CGI, but I don't think that is the reason...

Comment: check to make sure that /jalmar/app/View/elements/json.ctp is uploaded to your hosting.

Comment: It is, and I have even tried to rename the folder with a lowercase e, as it starts with E on the server

Comment: why you have View instead of views? are you using winodws or linux in localhost? in windows folder and file names are not caseSensitive but in linux it is

Comment: I just had to try to rename the folder to lowercase e again, and then it worked.
I discovered that in the AppController where I use the element, I had written the path to elements with a lowercase e, which was the reason that it couldn't find the view.

Thanks for the comments

Comment: @jonesw Thank you very much for question and answer. That solved my problem in 5 minutes :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I wrote in the comments, the error was that I had written the path to elements with a lowercase e in my AppController. This worked on my localhost as a windows, but not in my host using unix... Thought I had tried to change it but apperently not.
As this is my first question on stack overflow, so is okay that I accept my own answer to close the question?

Comment: Congrats on the solution.  When you are able, please mark your answer as 'accepted' so that others might learn from your success.  Cheers~